# Makefile help/clarification with Assert and -B

Tags: c, makefile

I am having issues with makefile and compiling using assert. For an assignment I am supposed to compile using make -B FLAG=-DNDEBUG to turn off debug mode and make -B to turn it on. I am unsure what -B does and I don't understand the documentation for it "-B, --always-make  Unconditionally make all targets" (From the man pages). If someone could help that would be amazing!

Comment: You sure you read `-B` (always make) and not `-D` (define a variable)?

Comment: Do you know how to write the C code so that it will compile in non-debug mode if NDEBUG is defined, but in debug mode if it is not? (Your teacher must love negatives.)

Comment: `make` does not accept the `-D` flag, so yes, he definitely read `-B` not `-D`.  make defines variables using assignment syntax just as Patrick showed: `FLAGS=-DNDEBUG`.  @Beta note that `NDEBUG` is a macro defined by the C/C++ standard (if set then all `assert` calls are turned into no-ops at compile time), it's not something a teacher makes up and doesn't require anyone to write any code to support it.

Comment: @MadScientist: Thanks, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MadScientist to point out the mistake in my answer.
(-D is compiler option, not an option for make instruction)

**[Answer after correction]**
make FLAG=-DNDEBUG
or
make -B FLAG=-DNDEBUG

In this case, you must be having your own custom makefile.
The flag defined with make instruction can be used in makefile to add the compiler option.
e.g.
Makefile ->
all:
    gcc $FLAG -o test -c test.c

**[Answer before correction]**
make                  --->   If first time, then fresh build, if successive calls, then incremental build only for modified source files or linking of updated libraries

make -B               --->   Fresh build always, instead of incremental build

make -B -DNDEBUG      ---> to turn off debug logs (as per your code usage of NDEBUG macro to control debug code), do fresh build always

Example code using NDEBUG macro to control debugging of function call sequence:

```
void test_func()
{
#ifndef NDEBUG
    printf("%s::%d::++Entered\n, __func__, __LINE__);
#endif /* NDEBUG */

     /* Your code goes here */
     ...

#ifndef NDEBUG
    printf("%s::%d::--Exiting\n, __func__, __LINE__);
#endif /* NDEBUG */

}
```

When make -B (or make) is used for compiling your program, the program will print the debug logs on execution.

When make -B -DNDEBUG (or make -DNDEBUG) is used for compiling your program, then debug logs will not be printed since NDEBUG symbol is defined this time.

Comment: As above, you can't define variables on the `make` command line using `-D`; `make -B -DNDEBUG` is an error.  Also, the original question was about `assert` so there's no need to use `#ifndef NDEBUG` etc. in the code.  If your code uses `assert()` calls then merely adding `-DNDEBUG` to the _compile_ line will disable them.